# Show only all non-black, non-white pixels with Imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a (greyscale) image that is almost entirely, but not quite, bitonal. I'd like to see all the pixels that aren't exactly black or white.

How can I do this with Imagemagick?

---

[*I figured out one way, I'll still accept the best other method!*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick has a more or less reverse version of "-opaque" if you start it with a plus "+" instead of a dash "-". This command will change all pure white and pure black pixels to white, and all other pixels to red...

```
magick bw_img.png -colorspace rgb ^
  -fill white -opaque black -fill red +opaque white result.png
```

After setting the colorspace, the first "-opaque" operation will fill every pure black pixel with white. All the white pixels are, of course, already white.

Then change the fill color to red, and the "+opaque" operation will fill every pixel that is *not* pure white with red.

That is in Windows syntax. For "nix systems, that continued-line caret "^" should be changed to a backslash "\" or just turn the command into a single line.

For ImageMagick v6 change "magick" to "convert".

Edited to Add...

Your solution using "-transparent" is effective, and may be the best answer for some workflows. Keep in mind there is a similar option with a plus "+" you can use with the "-transparent" operator. Just as an example, this will create a totally transparent version of an input image...

```
magick logo: -background none -transparent red +transparent red result.png
```

First it changes every pure red pixel to transparent, then it turns everything that is *not* pure red to transparent.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple - though not maybe the fastest.

```
# Make any pixel that is pure black or white into white, else black
magick image.png -fx '(u==0)||(u==1)' result.png
```

Or, obviously, the converse:

```
# Make any pixel that is neither pure black nor pure white into white, else black
magick image.png -fx '(u>0)&&(u<1)' result.png
```

Comment: While this is perhaps not the "canonical" solution for the question as written, it is also a  solution to the extended class of problem: find the pixels that are not _nearly_ white or black (by changing `1` to something else). So +1, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with

```
convert input.png -transparent black -transparent white \
  -alpha extract -negate \
  -colorspace rgb -fill red -opaque black \
  output.png
```

The thinking is like this:

- Convert all black pixels to tranparent: `-transparent black`
- Ditto for white `-transparent white`
- Now we have a transparent image with the only non-transparent pixels being the non-black, non-white ones
- Copy the alpha channel to the image: `-alpha extract`. Now all the old BW pixels are black, the others are white.
- Negate the image: `-negate`. Now all the old BW pixels are white, the others are black.

You can stop here if a black-on-white image is what you want. I wanted them red, so:

- Change to RGB colorspace (because my image was greyscale): `-colorspace rgb`
- Set the fill color to red: `-fill red`
- And apply it to all black pixels (i.e. those that were not black or white): `-opaque black`